# Movie about a guy who uses a notebook to relive and fix horrible accidents that he and his friends caused

Tags: identify-this-movie

Unfortunately I don't remember much from the movie, since I saw only 30 minutes of it, but I remember few scenes. I will describe the movie as much as possible.

- *Film genre:* Fantasy (most likely)
- *Year of release:* Considering, I was not older than 12 at the time, it would be around 2000 to 2008.
- *Language:* It was translated to Russian, but I heard some English words, because of bad dubbing.
- *Filmed in:* I am 90% sure that was USA.

Characters:

- *Protagonist:* (15-18) year old guy, jeans jacket and longish hair. (I think darkish blonde).
- *Girl:* (15-18) year old girl, who loved the protagonist, had a brother, and I think she was blonde.
- *Fat boy:* (15-16) year old boy. I don't want to be rude, but that is only characteristic that I remember..
- *Crazy boy:* (14-15) year old boy. He was very emotional and could not control himself. He was as emotionally stable, as [Jack Torrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Torrance) from [The Shining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shining_(film)). The blonde girl was his sister.
- *Dog:* He was a white little dog. His master was the protagonist.

Before I start describing scenes from movie, I would like to say, that it was pretty unsafe for kids. Text that is **Bolded** is important to the story.

1. There were a pack of kids, who did pranks on people. (The protagonist of this movie was one of them). They made a prank on a women, by putting firecracker in the mailbox, and when the women opened it, the firecracker blew up, and killed her. **(Kids were hiding behind big tree, 20 meters from mailbox).**
2. Later in the movie, the hero tried to save the women three times.

   - First: By screaming, not to open it. (He failed)
   - Second: By sending his fat friend to disarm the firecracker. (His friend failed and died.)
   - Third: He tried to disarm it, but it blew up, killing the protagonist. (I think this was the ending).
3. Either after the fat kid, or women dying, the protagonist went to a high-security prison. There he was in cell with a black dude (who was reading some book). The protagonist asked him where his notebook was. After about a minute, the black dude asked the protagonist to show him his palms. On both of them, there were (some signs). The black dude said, "You are the chosen one", or something like that. The black guy, for reason I don't remember started to taunt other prison mates, who killed him in his cell.
4. There was some scene where the blonde girl told her brother (crazy guy), that she had sex with the protagonist. In rage, the crazy guy proceeds to beat the protagonist and his sister to pulp. **(This is an important moment)**.

When the protagonist went back to that moment of his life, he tried three things to change the situation.

- Tried to beat the crazy guy (that failed). The crazy guy went nuts and killed the protagonist.
- Told his fat friend, to kill the crazy guy from behind, when the protagonist would talk to the crazy guy. **(The fat kid succeeded)**
- Tried to talk him out of killing him and his sister. (That ended up with, the crazy guy, putting the protagonist's dog into a potato bag, and putting it on fire.)
  That was the worst scene.

  5. After the fat guy, succeeded in killing the crazy guy, the protagonist appeared in a mental hospital, where he visited the fat kid (now, about 18-20 years old). The fat kid was lying on a bed where he was held by leather straps. (The fat guy was really angry at him.)

That is pretty much all I remember. I hope you guys will able to help me find it.

Comment: funny, when I read `(Kids were hiding behind big tree, 20 meters from mailbox)` the first idea was "butterfly effect".

Comment: Age 15-18 is classified as an "old guy" to you? :/

Comment: The mailbox bomb sure and many other details definitely sound like The Butterfly Effect, but at no point during the movie did the protagonist die... (unless you count the alternate ending)

Comment: Excellent detalization on this ID request! Bravo! I wish all of them were just as good.

Comment: @DangerZone Pretty sure you have to read `(15-18) old guy` as `15 to 18 year old guy`, then it makes some kind of sense.

Comment: @pipe - Yup... That's probably it... ha

Comment: @deadfish: I thought butterfly effect after reading the title ;)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is *[The Butterfly Effect](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0289879/)*  (2004).

**From Wikipedia:**

> Kutcher plays 20-year-old college student Evan Treborn, with Amy Smart as his childhood sweetheart Kayleigh Miller, William Lee Scott as her sadistic brother Tommy, and Elden Henson as their neighbor Lenny. Evan finds he has the ability to travel back in time to inhabit his former self (that is, his adult mind inhabits his younger body) and to change the present by changing his past behaviors. Having been the victim of several childhood traumas aggravated by stress-induced memory losses, he attempts to set things right for himself and his friends, but there are unintended consequences for all. The film draws heavily on flashbacks of the characters' lives at ages 7 and 13, and presents several alternate present-day outcomes as Evan attempts to change the past, before settling on a final outcome.